# Which one is the best to draw a grid?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Which one is the best:

1. to use Line object from kineticjs or
2. to use moveto() and lineto() methods of canvas?

[image]
In my example I have used Line objects but so I have about 250 objects. Could this overload the browsers capacity? Would the other method be better from this point of view?

Comment: There is never a *best* solution. Only the solution which works best for *you*.

Answer (score 2):

This grid is just a decorator, so there's no use in loading the scene graph of kineticsjs with it.

In your place i would evaluate those possibilities  :

- Draw lines with ( beginPath, moveTo, lineTo, closePath ) before each kinteicsjs draw.
- Draw once the background in a background canvas that you will drawImage to 'clear' your canvas each cycle.
- Layer two canvases, the one above being cleared each cycle (clearRect), and the one below having the grid on it.

Performance-wise, the layered canvases will be the fastest (i assume the grid is static here).

Rq : You have a big interest in having a separate drawGrid(context, columnCount, rowCount, *some other parameters*) function that will draw the grid on a context, so switching between any of the 3 options should be fast.